# How to test specific hSpec property using `--match` and cabal

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, testing, cabal, hspec

I have a bunch of test modules and I can run a specific one using cabal test.

```
cabal test Module.Name.Here
```

The module contains many tests and one of them fails and it gives the following message.

```
  To rerun use: --match "/Module.Name.Here/hspecDescribeString/hspecPropName/"
```

How do I use this match string? I've tried various combinations none of them works . I've also looked at `cabal test --help` it does not mention `--match` flag anywhere.

```
cabal test Module.Name.Here --match rest-of-the-match-string
cabal test Module.Name.Here -- --match rest-of-the-match-string
cabal test match-string
cabal test -- match-string
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it like this:

```
cabal test —test-options=—match=/Module.Name.Here/hspecDescribeString/hspecPropName/
```

Comment: In my case I had to wrap the options in quotes like this - `--test-options="--match=\"<match-string>\""`