# Benchmark one specific `Test.Tasty.Bench` benchmark in a module using `cabal bench`

Tags: haskell, testing, benchmarking, cabal

I have a bunch of benchmarks and I want to run a specific benchmark among them.

I had asked a previous [similar question for tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72237547/7588896). But the same technique does not work for benchmarks. Here are somethings I tried, where "benchmarkGroupName/benchmName" is the .

```sh
cabal test Module.Name.Here --benchmark-options="--match=\"<match-string>\""
cabal test Module.Name.Here --match=<match-string>
cabal test Module.Name.Here --benchmark-options="--pattern=\"<match-string>\""
```

It says something like

```sh
Invalid option `--match'

Usage: Module.Name.Here [-p|--pattern PATTERN] [-t|--timeout DURATION] 
                           [--stream-size ARG] [-l|--list-tests] 
                           [-j|--num-threads NUMBER] [-q|--quiet] 
                           [--hide-successes] [--color never|always|auto] 
                           [--ansi-tricks ARG] [--baseline ARG] [--csv ARG] 
                           [--svg ARG] [--stdev ARG] [--fail-if-slower ARG] 
                           [--fail-if-faster ARG]
```

Nothing works I've also looked at the [documentation](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/setup-commands.html?highlight=benchmark-options#cmdoption-runhaskell-Setup.hs-test-benchmark-options) but it's not helpful.

Comment: This works for me: `cabal bench --benchmark-options="--pattern \"test\""` (also with `=`)

Comment: You can do `cabal bench --benchmark-options="--help"` to see all options.

Comment: Hmmm this is does work if I use `benchName` only. But when I give `benchGroup/benchName` it fails saying cannot parse pattern. Surely there must be a way to give the path?

Comment: Patterns are awk expressions, see [the tasty documentation](https://github.com/UnkindPartition/tasty#patterns). You need to use `.` instead of `/`, so `benchGroup.benchName`.